# Implicit Plots in Python with Customizable Line Width?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can we increase the line width of plots produced by `plot_implicit` from Sympy? Neither I can find a parameter designated to this [in the API](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit), nor does Google give any expedient cues.

I've read that, e.g., `plot_implicit(Eq(x1**2 + x2**2 - 1))._backend.ax` references an Axis object of Matplotlib, so I tried changing the default line width of Matplotlib prior to invoking `plot_implicit` from Sympy, but it doesn't make any change:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 10
```

In case that this isn't possible (which is hard to believe), what other options are there to produce implicit plots of functions in Python, such that the line width can be adapted?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`plot_implicit` documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit):

> `plot_implicit`, by default, uses interval arithmetic to plot functions. If the expression cannot be plotted using interval arithmetic, it defaults to a generating a contour using a mesh grid of fixed number of points.

This means that the resulting plot is not a line plot, for which the line width can be set in any way.
The mesh gridding effect can also be observed when zooming into the plot:
[image]